# How to prove linearity, find matrix relative to canonical basis and determine kernel and the image with given map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and considering the map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with given $f(x) = v x^T v$.

How can I proove, that $f$ is linear?

How can I find matrix $f$ relative to the canonical basis?

And how to determine the kernel and the image of $f$?

> Progress:
>
> For linearity, I need to prove: $f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$ and $f(\alpha b) = \alpha f(b)$:
>
> > $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f(x+y)=v(x+y)^Tv=v\left(x^T+y^T\right)v=vx^Tv+vy^Tv=f(x)+f(y)$
> >     $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(\alpha x)=v(\alpha x)^Tv=v\alpha (x)^Tv=\alpha vx^Tv=\alpha f(x)$
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Linearity **proved**

>

Comment: Do you what it means for a function to be linear?

Comment: A linear map is a map, that preserves addition and multiplication. Am I right?

Comment: In simple terms, yes. Can you write those properties with symbols?

Comment: Something like $f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$ and $f(\alpha b) = \alpha f(b)$?

Comment: Yes and it must hold for all $u,v\in \mathbb R^n$ and for all $\alpha\in \mathbb R$. Now can you show that given $u,v\in \mathbb R^n$ it holds that $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$?

Comment: So, can I state something like $x = x + 0$ and $(a + b)^T = a^T + b^T$ so, $f(x+0) = v (x+0)^T v = v (x^T + 0^T) v = vx^Tv + v0^Tv= vx^Tv$?

Comment: My bad, I shouldn't have used the letter $v$ because it's already being used. Let me change the variables to $x$ and $y$. You want to prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Can you tell me what $f(x+y)$ is? What about $f(x)+f(y)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20250/discussion-between-pobdr-and-git-gud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you find matrix $A$ representing  $f$ with respect to the standard basis?
i will take $n = 2$ and general result should be similar. let $v = \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2}$ and the standard basis $\left\{e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0}, e_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1}  \right\}.$

the first coulmn of $A$ is $Ae_1 = T(e_1) = \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2} v_1$ because the inner product $v^Te_1 = v_1$ therefore we have 
$Ae_1 = \pmatrix{v_1v_1\\v_1v_2}  $ similarly $Ae_2 = \pmatrix{v_2v_2\\v_2v_2}  $

finally here is the matrix $$ A = \pmatrix{v_1v_1 & v_2v_1\\v_1v_2 & v_2v_2}.$$

how do you find the kernel and the image of $f$.

the image of $x$ under $f$ is always a multiple of $v$ so $image(f) = \alpha v$ for any number $\alpha$ the one dimensional space spanned by $v.$

the kernel of $f$ consists of all $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ that implies $x^Tv = 0$ that is the orthogonal complement of the $kernel(f).$